# Import CSV to CMS Made Simple database through admin

Tags: php, cmsmadesimple

I created a new table called 'products' with about 30 fields in it. It's for a custom modification I did to the website. I have a CSV file with 200 products in it and currently I go to phpmyadmin then delete tables current rows and import the CSV. Now my client wants to update the product list by him self and upload it to the database. He can update the CSV easily but is there a way I can let him upload it to that particular table through CMSMS admin panel so he doesn't have to mess with phpmyadmin? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check code from frontendusers module which have import module from csv. 
I hope it help.